# How does JWT Token Works?

Tags: jwt

I'm very new to this JWT token stuff. I had created the token for the text `batman`, which gave me:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInppcCI6IkRFRiJ9.eNqqViouTVKyUkpKLMlNzFOqBQAAAP__.Q_tupftGHJ-S1p2Ocopzt7CUYCm3PeLncnifL7EXBeguIHUfwMiP0AZQUO607MViwwQk4g-Kxnbrz7xmifkfPA
```

I restarted my server, thought that JWT would keep the calculated tokens in memory, however after re-start, when I pass the above token still JWT could able to authenticate it!

Can anyone explain how this is possible? Does it use any algorithm for the same?

Answer (score 1):

Check the TimetoLive TTL property of your properties file used in JWT token.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question, let see how does JWT token works.

1. Let's take example of 'Client' (A) and 'Server' (B).
2. The Client(A) wants to access some protected data on our Server(B), but the Server knows Clients cannot be trusted.
3. The Server only wants to give the data to a trustworthy Client. So our Client sends a request to our Server along with data to verify who it is.
4. Instead of saving the user data, the Server instead creates a token and this token is returned to the Client and it's up to the Client to store this data, and send it along as required for any requests to the Server.
5. The next time our Client makes a request along a secure route, It sends along the job token.
6. But our Server knows not to trust the Client, So our Server verifies this token
   is who it says it's from and that it hasn't been tampered with.
7. If everything checks out to be OK, the Server sends back a response with the requested data. That's it !!.

Note : The below link explains different algorithm used to generate JWT. Along with that it also contains details about different tech stack supporting different algorithms.

https://jwt.io/